# Strict Alternation for 3 processes

Tags: c++, c, linux, operating-system, theory

Well, Recently I have come to learn Strict Alternation while studying operating systems concepts. To reduce chances of race condition and handle two processes we go like this:

Process 0:

```
While (TRUE) {

    while (turn != 0); // wait
    critical_section();
    turn = 1;
    noncritical_section();}

}
```

Process 1:

```
While (TRUE) {

    while (turn != 1); // wait
    critical_section();
    turn = 0;
    noncritical_section();

}
```

**But I'm wondering how I can handle 3 processes to reduce racing condition even more?**

My approach is:
Process 0:

```
while (turn != 0 && turn != 2); // wait
critical_section();
turn = 1;
noncritical_section();}
```

Process 1:

```
while (turn != 1 && turn != 0); // wait
critical_section();
turn = 2;
noncritical_section();}
```

Process 3:

```
while (turn != 1 && turn != 2); // wait
critical_section();
turn = 0;
noncritical_section();}
```

Is my approach okay? what do you guys suggest? and are there anything better out there?

**Thanks**

Comment: Is there a particular problem you are encountering? Is something not working? Is there particular technical detail you are asking about? If not, you should direct requests for feedback on working code to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the thing is. this is a theoretical question. I learned the code to handle two processes. I just want to know if my approach to handle 3 processes using strict alternation is working? or if there any better solution to this.

Comment: The problem with these kinds of questions is that the answer to "Is there anything better out there?" is almost definitively "Probably". It's unlikely that you have come up with the perfect solution, one which can't be improved. And it's not a common enough problem for there to be a unanimously accepted ideal solution, so there isn't likely to be a definitive correct answer. In addition to that, there is no context given which would help justify a solution over another. It's a toss up for me rather this question is too broad or primarily opinion based.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I see. Thanks :D

Comment: After rereading the question, I noticed that your waiting mechanism is to loop until the condition changes. This is known as spinning and is not generally seen as a good strategy. For one, the "idle" threads will still consume CPU resources. They wouldn't have to with a proper synchronization primitive. Second, unless `turn` is a proper atomic type, reading from it without synchronization is likely to be undefined behavior. Since you are using critical sections, I would guess that it is not a proper atomic type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I know, CPU is always being used. This is a disadvantage of this approach. There are better solutions nowadays, were  are being taught this for the sake of learning. and about `turn`, it is synchronized but we don't show it, because this is totally theoretical and just for understanding how things work.

Answer (score 1):

With what you have it wouldn't necessarily strictly alternate anyway, for instance, it could go into turn = 0 and the turn = 1 or turn = 2 code could follow. My suggestion would be to use OS-level events, one for each code path and each process triggers the one that follows.

Answer (score 1):

With all the justified criticism on the presented concept, no one yet cared to correct the error in the posted approach.

The general pattern is simple in each process:

- while it's not *my* turn, wait
- do *critical section*
- set turn to *next* process
- …

So, the posted `while (turn …)` conditions in the case of 3 processes are, as SoronelHaetir noted, wrong. For process 0 and 1 they have to stay the same as in the 2-process case; generally for process `i` it's `while (turn != i) ; // wait`.